# Can I manage sudoers from Open Directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory, sudo, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

I have configured Open Directory & integrated it with Microsoft Active Directory so that the users sync with Open Directory.  Now I want to manage sudo commands from Open Directory.  Is this possible to manage **sudoers** from the Windows server (not from each client i.e. /etc/sudoers in each).

Comment: https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.ldap.man.html. This involves adding schemas to your directory server.

Comment: I added the text "..from the Windows server" because it wasn't clear before if you were wanting to control sudoers from your Windows ("main server") or from an OSX server.  Is that correct?

Comment: Can you add a bit of information about which versions of OSX and OSX-server you are running, and also why do you need to control suoders?   In OSX it is much easier to control the ACLs and other than controlling who is an administrator or not, I haven't seen sudo used much (in terms of Server on Macs).  If you are hoping to admin sudoers with the OSX Server front end, I'm happy to write an answer that explains this is not possible at all :)